# Change font and backgroundcolor of a line in a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, joptionpane

I use a `JList` in a `JOptionPane` to show lines in a dialog.
I simply want to change the background color and font of the lines (depending on the content of the line).

I can't achieve and did not find any useful article on this.
My actual problem is, that the method `getListCellRendererComponent` in my following code is never called. Dialog shows up with one line "any text for one line", but no color/font changes.

can anybody help ?

```
    final DefaultListModel d = new DefaultListModel();
    final JList list = new JList(d);

    ListCellRenderer renderer = new ListCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setText(value.toString());

            label.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, 12));
            label.setBackground(new Color(12, 12, 12));

            int i = 1 / 0;  // <<<<<<  --- does not throw an error, so it doesn't get into this.
            return label;
        }
    };
    list.setCellRenderer(renderer);

    for (int iList = 0; iList < alSuggestionsText.size(); iList++) {
        // bigList[iList] = alTexte.get(iList);
        d.addElement(alSuggestionsText.get(iList));
        // jlist.add(bigList);
    }

    final String sIgronreText = "any text for one line";

    d.addElement(sIgronreText);

    final JList jlist = new JList(d);

    JOptionPane jpane = new JOptionPane();
    jpane.showMessageDialog(null, jlist, sWikiidtemp, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different JLists. First one where you set ListCellRenderrer.

```
list.setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

and another one you display in dialog:

```
pane.showMessageDialog(null, jlist, "adsfasdf", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Add:

```
    final JList jlist = new JList(d);
    jlist.setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

to get it working.

Comment: Oh my good. I am so stupid !!!! Yes you are right. Thank you so much for looking into it so detailed. I am so happy now :-)